# Why CodeContracts Static Analyzer doesn't make warnings?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, code-contracts, contracts

I have several user controls, that are subscribed to the event handler in another class.
I'm learning CodeContracts in C#, and I wonder, why does Static Analyzer allows writing code like this:

```
void MyUserControl_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  MyUserControl item = sender as MyUserControl;      
  item.DoSomething(); // I expect some warning here, because item can be null

  sender.Equals(testObject); // This doesn't yield warning either 
}
```

Here I have a potentially unsafe code, that can lead to null-reference exception. 
I understand, that static analyzer probably cannot check, what will the actual type of `sender` be. But in case it cannot prove it, I expect some warning, like `CodeContracts: Possibly calling a method on a null reference`.

Or do I get some idea of contracts wrong? How can I get notified of errors like this?

**UPD:**

Yes, I did enable `Implicit Non-Null Obligation` as it was suggested in the answers, but I still don't get a warning from Static Analyzer. Also I tried to run Code Analysis with `Microsoft All Rules` rules set, also no warning. (But I'd prefer dealing with Code Contracts and perform some additional checks using Contract class, rather then with if-then-throw or something else)

Comment: Did you enable "implicit null contracts"?

Answer (score 3):

You should enable "Implicit Non-Null obligations" in the static analyzer options (Project Options|Code Analysis).

Answer (score 0):

"How can I get notified of errors like this?": Resharper will warn you in that case.

<s>Code contracts will warn you that the object might be null if there is a "Requires" that the object be non-null.  You're asking for an implicit "Requires" for an object dereference, which seems reasonable on the face of it, but which CC for whatever reason doesn't seem to provide.</s>

The documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx says that it does enforce such an implicit contract.  I'm looking into it further.

RedHat beat me to it.  More detail: You should check the "Implicit Non-Null Obligations" box under "Static Checking" in the Code Contracts tab of your project properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I had to turn up the warning level slider on the same panel as the "Implicit Non-Null obligations" checkbox.

Answer (score -1):

In **properties** page of your project on **Code Analysis** tab you can change **Rules**.

Comment: Code Analysis != Code Contracts